# How to overlay 3 functions on one plot using R

Tags: r, plot

I have three functions and a plot code:

```
f1 <- function(c){0.187*c-0.000236*c^2+0.194*10-0.00330*100-0.000406*10}
f2 <- function(c){0.187*c-0.000236*c^2+0.194*16.53-0.00330*(16.53^2)-0.000406*16.53}
f3 <- function(c){0.187*c-0.000236*c^2+0.194*20-0.00330*400-0.000406*20}
```

I wish to plot all three of these on the same graph. I currently have:

```
png("figure.png")
plot(f1(1:1000), type="l", xlab="x", ylab="y", main="the plot :)")
plot(f2(1:1000), type="l", xlab="x", ylab="y", add = T)
dev.off()
```

So far this produces just *f1* on a plot as opposed to *f1* and *f2*. I believe I am taking the wrong approach because I am producing **another plot** and trying to add it to a pre-existing plot. I am unsure whether to use geom_line or something similar and just overlay it.

Is there a straight forward way to plot multiple functions and overlay them in the same plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_line` is for `ggplot2`, which is an entirely different plotting system.

If you start with `plot()`, you can use `lines()` to draw lines on your current plot. Your lines are pretty close together, so it doesn't matter much here, but with base `plot` you usually want to calculate the maximum range in advance so your can set your plot window up right from the start:

```
x = 1:1000
y1 = f1(x)
y2 = f2(x)
y3 = f3(x)

y_range = range(c(y1, y2, y3))

plot(x, y1, ylim = y_range, type="l", xlab="x", ylab="y", main="the plot :)", col = "red")
lines(x, y2, col = "blue")
lines(x, y3, col = "chartreuse")
```

[image]

`ggplot2` is made to work with data in data frames - particularly long-format data frames. Here's how we might approach the problem with `ggplot`. (Note that, unlike above, `ggplot` calculates the plot limits and gives a nice legend automatically.)

```
library(ggplot2)
dd = data.frame(x, y1, y2, y3)
d_long = reshape2::melt(data = dd, id.vars = "x", variable.name = "fun", value.name = "y")
ggplot(d_long, aes(x = x, y = y, color = fun)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OR  sticking with base R plotting like your code,  you can just add the extra functions using `lines`

```
plot(f1(1:1000), type="l", xlab="x", ylab="y", main="the plot :)")
lines(1:1000, f2(1:1000))
lines(1:1000, f3(1:1000))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want two plots one right next to the other, you have to set the parameter of your palette. Use par(mfrow=c(1,2)) after the png() command.

```
png("figure.png")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(f1(1:1000), type="l", xlab="x", ylab="y", main="the plot :)")
plot(f2(1:1000), type="l", xlab="x", ylab="y", add = T)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

For functions you can also use `curve`:

```
f1 <- function(c){0.187*c-0.000236*c^2+0.194*10-0.00330*100-0.000406*10}
f2 <- function(c){0.187*c-0.000236*c^2+0.194*16.53-0.00330*(16.53^2)-0.000406*16.53}
f3 <- function(c){0.187*c-0.000236*c^2+0.194*20-0.00330*400-0.000406*20}

c0 <- 1
c <- 1000
curve(f1, c0, c, main = 'the plot :)', xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y')
curve(f2, c0, c, add = T)
curve(f3, c0, c, add = T)
```

[image: r programming curve]

As @Gregor noted, `geom_line()` is a `ggplot()` call. To go all into the `tidyverse`, you can do:

```
#or with ggplot / geom_line
library(tidyverse)

map_df(list(f1 =f1,f2 =  f2,f3 = f3), exec, 1:1000)%>%
  mutate(x = 1:1000)%>%
  gather(key = fx,value = value, -x)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, col = fx)) + geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot and purrr multiple functions]

Finally, you may be interested in `facet_grid` as well:

```
map_df(list(f1 =f1,f2 =  f2,f3 = f3), exec, 1:1000)%>%
  mutate(x = 1:1000)%>%
  gather(key = fx,value = value, -x)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value)) + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(fx))
```

[image: ggplot facet_grid]